# How to reshape numpy image?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, reshape

I have an image as a numpy array with shape `(channels, height, width)` how can I reshape it so that it has shape `(height, width, channels)`?

Comment: you can't use `numpy_image.reshape(height, width, channels)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume it would be quicker to use the built-in numpy function.

```
np.rollaxis(array_name,0,3).shape
```

Comment: don't you mean `np.rollaxis(array_name,0,3).shape`, yours will reorder it as `(height, channels, width)`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I got my directions confused. I will update my original post.

Comment: This function continues to be supported for backward compatibility, but you should prefer moveaxis. The moveaxis function was added in NumPy 1.11.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`transpose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) to choose the order of the axes. In this case you want:

```
array.transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

This creates a new view onto the original array whenever possible (no data will be copied).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np
newim = np.zeros((height, width, channels))
for x in xrange(channels):
    newim[:,:,x] = im[x,:,:]
```